# How to set SetEnv in nginx like it is done in Apache?

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails

I am running ubuntu, rvm, passenger, with a rails 3 application.

I have to set the GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH using SetEnv in my host file as its done in Apache, but I am not sure how this is done in nginx.

Can this be done somehow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In my /etc/init.d/nginx script, can I set environmental variables?](http://serverfault.com/questions/209239/in-my-etc-init-d-nginx-script-can-i-set-environmental-variables)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using CGI then the link below documents the method of assigning string, variables and values  which are passed to the nginx FastCGI server.

http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpFcgiModule#fastcgi_param